# const reference can be assigned an int?

Tags: c++, memory, reference, constants

I came across a code snippet

```
const int& reference_to_const_int = 20;
cout<<"\n  reference_to_const_int = "<<reference_to_const_int<<endl;
```

This code compiles & executes with output :-

```
reference_to_const_int = 20
```

This is something strange in for me. As I know reference do not occupy memory & they are aliases to other variables. hence we cannot say

```
int& reference_to_int = 30;
```

The above statement shall not compile giving error :-

```
 error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
```

What exactly is happening in the "const int&" case? A full explanation is desired.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Read this: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: Giving it a bit more thought, it seems like it would *have* to be legal.  If it wasn't, you'd never really be able to set it without making more variables.

Comment: @GigaWatt: What is the "it" you are talking about?  Believe me, if "it" *should* be legal, it *would* be. :)

Comment: References **do** occupy memory.  References are similar to pointers, except you don't need to explicitly dereference them and can't change what they point to. References take up memory just like pointers do. If you have a reference as a member of a class it has to take up memory to record which object it refers to (e.g. by storing its address, as a pointer would.)

Comment: @GigaWatt: C++ differs between initialization and assignment. `const int &x = 50;` is not "setting" (assigning), but rather initialization.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: Thanks for the link. It has a good explanation. "only lvalues can be bound to references to non-const" is the basic reason of the error.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it is unspecified whether a references takes storage (see [dcl.ref]/4) . In this case it seems likely to me that no storage would be used for the reference; only for the object being referred to.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, true, although in this case I wouldn't even expect storage for the object being referred to, its value is constant and its address doesn't escape so it can be in a register and not take any stack space for the reference or the temporary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A temporary is created, and it's legal to bind a `const` reference to it, but illegal to bind it to a non-`const` one.

It's just like:

```
const int& reference_to_const_int = int(20);  //LEGAL
      int& reference_to_const_int = int(20);  //ILLEGAL
```

A `const` reference extends the life of a temporary, that's why this works. It's just a rule of the language.

Comment: doesn't the temporary go out of scope after the assignment statement so the print statement references an `int` which has gone out of scope?

Comment: @FlorianSowade no, const references extend the life of a temporary.

Comment: But beware, const references do not extend lifetime in ALL cases.  And also note that Microsoft C++ compilers break the rules and do allow binding non-`const` references to temporaries.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah I only learned the VC++ part recently, and turned off all language extensions in MSVS. Best decision I took recently.

Comment: Specifically, automatic const references extend the life of the temporary (and I think namespace scope const references do too, I just can't be bothered to check). Data members of const reference type *don't* extend temporaries bound to them, so don't try this trick in an initializer list.

Comment: @SteveJessop last part - they do, but until the end of the constructor. Not really helpful... (the feature I mean, not your comment) :)

Comment: @Luchian: good point, I assume that's in order to match the fact that temporaries in initializer expressions persist until the end of the initialization, not just until the end of the full expression in which they appear. And yes, this is rarely as long as the author of the code hoped.

Comment: @Luchian [OT] Turning off language extensions isn't supported by Microsoft! See [Warning Guidelines for VC](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/212180). You should turn up the warnings level instead.

Comment: @Bo: "I also asked for /Za to be removed from VC11". Wtf? Sounds like Herb Sutter (or someone at MS) needs to knock some heads together. Bug tennis is a fine game, but probably shouldn't be played in public.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is easier to understand when we look at what happens when we bind a reference to a temporary object. If we write

```
const int& reference_to_const_int = 20; //A temporay object int(20) is created.
```

the compiler transforms above code into something like this:

```
int temp = 20;
const int& reference_to_const_int = temp;
```

If reference_to_const_int were not const, then we could assign a new value to reference_to_const_int. Doing so would not change literal 20 but would instead change temp, which is a temporary object and hence inaccessible.
Allowing only const references to be bound to values requiring temporaries avoids the problem entirely because a const reference is read-only.

**Why do C++ allows const references to accept temporary objects or RVALUES (like literals)?**

The most common places we see references are as function arguments or return values. 
When a reference is used as a function argument, any modification to the reference inside the function will cause changes to the argument outside the function.

If function can expect/accept temporary objects or literals as inputs and if the function respects const-ness of the object, making the argument a const reference will allow the function to be used in all situations.

Temporary objects are always const, so if you don’t use a const reference, that argument won’t be accepted by the compiler.

```
void f(int&) {}
void g(const int&) {}
int main() 
{
    //f(1); //Error
    g(1); //OK 
}
```