# Assignment operator is not calling parameterized constructor while copy constructor present in code

Tags: c++, object, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

**CASE 1:**
When I create a object of class with an assignment operator , it calls parameterized constructor if there in no copy constructor in code.

Below code is without copy constructor:

```
class Test{
    public:
    int a;
    Test(int a){
        this->a = a;
    }
};
int main(){
    Test x = 6;
    cout<<x.a;
    return 0;
}
```

**CASE 2:**
But if there is copy constructor present in class then it gives error if I use assignment operator while declaring class object.

Error : cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Test&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Test’

Below code is with copy constructor

```
class Test{
    public:
    int a;
    Test(int a){
        this->a = a;
    }
    Test(Test &b){
       this->a = b.a;
    }

};
int main(){
    Test x = 6;
    cout<<x.a;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how just presence of copy constructor  is result ending up with error ? . With presence of copy constructor also my program should call Parameterize constructer when I assign a parameter to object of class.

Comment: The `=` in an initialization is not the assignment operator. The distinction between initialization and assignment is very important in C++.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should get used to use constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `Test(int a) : a(a) {}` (or better with separate name for the parameter: `Test(int b) : a(b) {}`. Especially if complex types are involved this prefers direct initialisation by value over default initialisation + assignment. Apart from, some members are *only* initialisable this way (constant members, references, non-default-constructable types, ...).

Comment: The problem is that your own copy constructor takes a *non*-const reference. You would see the same error with `void f(int&){} int main() { f(6); }`

Comment: Your 'copy' constructor is totally flawed, by the way: At first it should accept a `const` object, and it shouldn't try to copy the (uninitialised!) `this` into the other object, but the other way round. So together with initialiser list (see my comment before), it should look like: `Test(Test const& b) : a(b.a) {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this:

```
Test(Test &b){
   this->a = b.a;
}
```

Should actually be this:

```
Test(Test const &b){
   this->a = b.a;
}
```

Copy constructor should get a const reference, and they should copy the parameter content into the current object content, not the other way around..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801894/const-reference-can-be-assigned-an-int)
Because explain the const and non-const variable.
It's because explain this error:

> Error : cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Test&’ to an
> rvalue of type ‘Test’

C++ alow this, because it's initialization:

```
int main(){
    Test x=6;//initialization "const Test& obj = 6" OK
}
```

But C++ doesn't allow this(non-const value):

```
int main(){
    Test x=6;//initialization "Test& obj = 6" Not Ok!
}
```